# How to check if a `Integer` is greater than another `Integer` "easily" / "efficiently"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, comparison, integer

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to check if a `Integer` is greater than `0` and, more in general, if a `Integer` is greater than another `Integer`.

There is some Ruby or Ruby on Rails *method* to make that "easily" / "efficiently"?

---

*Note*: I would like to use / state that *method* in my view files and I think, if that method do not "exist", it could be better to state a "dedicated" method in my model or controller file and use that method in my views.

Comment: Yeah, can you say why the `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, `==` and `!=` operators *don't* work for you? The `Integer` class makes use of the `Comparable` module, which should make these operators available to you.

Comment: (And comparisson operators in Ruby *are* methods. Here is the [Comparable module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html) -- note that `>` is just a method defined in it, although it is specialized in Fixnum.)

Comment: @normalocity - I never said "the `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, `==` and `!=` operators *don't* work for me".

Comment: @user12882 But neither has it been explained why said *methods* (with syntactical magic) are not "easy" or "efficient" .. `1 > 2` is equivalent to `1.__send__(:>, 2)` and both result in false.

Comment: (Note that `1 > 2` can *also* be written as `(1).>(2)`, if that feels more like a *method* .. the first parenthesis are needed in this example because a literal is used and a bare `1.` would be treated as a floating point value: `a.>(b)` doesn't need quotes. Of course, you can create as many proxy methods as you desire .. in the end they will all use `Integer > Integer` though.)

Comment: You're not going to get anything easier / more efficient than `0 < my_num`, which _is_ a method. If that's not good enough, you at least need to say why.

Comment: I'd feel bad giving this another -1, but I'd like to strongly suggest to the author that he/she reword the question to explain what is needed beyond the built-in methods. Even after the edit it still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Integer_comparison#Ruby):

```
a = (print "enter a value for a: "; gets).to_i
b = (print "enter a value for b: "; gets).to_i

puts "#{a} is less than #{b}" if a < b
puts "#{a} is greater than #{b}" if a > b
puts "#{a} is equal to #{b}" if a == b
```

You can use standard Ruby within your views between `<%` and `%>`. And yes, you could implement a helper do to the check and use that helper method in your view.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever I start comparing more than two integers, I usually revert to array#max.

```
a = 1
b = 2
[0, a, b].max == a # false

a = 3
[0, a, b].max == a # true
```

The primary weakness of this is if a == b, so a special check is required for that case. Or you can do:

```
[0, a, b + 1].max == a
```

or

```
[0, a, b].max == a && a != b
```

EDIT:
  This method would probably fit best in your helpers.

Comment: Fine! I looked for smth to replace `c = a < b ? a : b` and here it is: `c = [a, b].min`